# Angular - why my Array is not pushing elements?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have some Arrays of object that arrives from API call. I did all the steps to call the API service in my HomeComponent.ts and it response well.
At the first step "thi.mssData" is getting the Array from backend. But when I try to split the data and fill another array it comes out empty. Where I am doing wrong? Here one of the call that return an array of object.

```
    mssToDisplayOne() {
    this.mssService.getSpecialtyOne().subscribe((MSS) => {
      this.mssData = MSS;
      this.afternoon=[];
      this.morning=[];
      this.mssData.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.sessionid %2 == 1){
        this.morning.push(item);
      }else if(item.sessionid %2 == 0){
        this.afternoon.push(item);
      }
      });
      console.log("Mss",this.mssData)
      console.log(this.morning);

      console.log(this.afternoon);
   
      });
  }
```

So the console.log of this.mssData came out full.
While this.morning and this.afternoon came out empty.
I have initialized everything above.
[console.log of the Arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZUNZ.png)

Comment: It works for me when using an arrow function (`item => {}`) instead of a normal function (`function(item) {}`). https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfvhvb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I tried but the result still the same

Answer (score 1):

The `subscribe` method is asynchronous and won't wait for the console logs. If you put the console.logs inside the subscription it will be logged correctly.

Comment: can you show how the mssData array looks like. Please expand and paste it here.

Comment: I put it inside the foreach and now it's working, thanks!

Comment: There is an interface in the mssService that explain the structure of the mssData array, and it is this:                                                                                                                                   '''export interface MssInterface {
  operatingroom: number;
  sessionid: number;
  specialty: number;
  day: number;
} '''

Comment: @Caterina it still should still log the array even after the loop. It might be a hoisting issue. Can you try to do a  (for item of this.mssData) {
        if(item.sessionid %2 == 1){
        this.morning.push(item);
      }else if(item.sessionid %2 == 0){
        this.afternoon.push(item);
      }
      }

Comment: I've done it, still the same result. Before I thoght that solution was working but I' ve mistaken the logs.